# How can I activate a 24V electric lock with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, nfc, arduino-uno

Good! I have a circuit in which I connect an Arduino to an NFC Shield and it is to a protoboard. My goal is to activate an electric lock that works with 10-24V AC and DC, for this I have placed a transistor 2N2222 and a resistance of 330 Ohms. The problem that I have esque when I connect the plate protoboard to the lock, the LED is turned on, but the lock is immovable.

This is the scheme on which I have based myself to assemble everything.

[image: scheme]

And this is the image of how I have it armed:

[image: mounting]

And finally I have the code that I am using:

```
#include <PN532.h>
#include <SPI.h>

/*Chip select pin can be connected to D10 or D9 which is hareware optional*/
/*if you the version of NFC Shield from SeeedStudio is v2.0.*/
#define PN532_CS 10
PN532 nfc(PN532_CS);
#define  NFC_DEMO_DEBUG 1

const int control = 7 ;
const int speed = 200;

void setup(void) {
pinMode(control,  OUTPUT) ;}


void loop(void) {
digitalWrite(control, HIGH);
     delay(2000);
     digitalWrite(control, LOW);
     delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Hardware questions are off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about electronic circuit design and not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't happends because your supply in +5v (from USB) and can not change state of +24v equipment.
you should connect a +12v supply to the collector of your transistor.
do like this :
[image]

Comment: But the arduino feed it with the power supply of my computer, is not enough?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not enough. you Should Use a +12 or above power supply. this problem is only solves with increasing power supply. you can supply your arduino with usb and use 12v for your lock but you should make Concatenation between two gnd.

Comment: But I do not understand why you need to receive the 12V arduino, if I have a transistor to increase those volts for the lock.